Do TSs (Technical Specifications) need to be supported by a conforming compiler?
cppreference, probably based on official C++, documents technical specifications that are under the namespace std::experimental.
For example, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected
Under what conditions are TS (Technical Specifications) available in the standard library?
For example:

Is it up to the library implementor to provide them?
Can they be removed at any time?
Can one depend on them?
Does it matter in practice for portability?


What is C++ Technical Specification? and Is it safe to use a C++ Technical Specifications approved for a future standard in a earlier standard?

concerning the first bullet, it is always up to the library implementers what to implement. I suppose you mean: What do they need to implement for a standard conforming implementation

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-14.1.0/libstdc++/api/a01608.html https://libcxx.llvm.org/DesignDocs/ExperimentalFeatures.html https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/README.md#non-goals

@463035818_is_not_an_ai .  I see, so if I need is_detected in my program, it is better implement it myself. (i.e. copy the "possible implementation" in preference).

sorry, my comment was just a general nitpick. What i mean is that one could write a library with everything from the standard but without std::vector. It would be incomplete, but it would be a library. When a new standard comes out, it is natural that standard libraries only partially support new features for example

@463035818_is_not_an_ai, there is no std::is_detected, only std::experimental::is_detected, so what I get from all this is that a library not implementing std::experimental can still be conformant to the standard.

I mean, for all intents and purposes, being conformant to the standard is not what you care about, you only care about availability on the platforms you want to support. Heck, no compiler is standard conformant, just look at their list of bugs, yet you don't really care if they're conformant in this regard do you?

Heck, libraries aren't necessarily implementing all the std:: stuff -- std::experimental, I'd stay away from anything named like that. That's right up with std::broken, std::unsupported and std::will_haunt_you_later.

I believe the answers to your questions are:  under the condition that the compiler vendor implements them; no; yes; no; yes.
